# How to run same python code simultaneously in Linux with command

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell, command-line

I am calling a python script from my PHP website.

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /var/www/vhosts/website.com/test.py '.$search.'');
```

When my website get more traffic simultaneously the python script is re-executed & the previous execution is getting canceled. the script takes at least 10sec to process. How do I fix it?

Comment: What does "the previous execution is getting canceled" mean? Are you _entirely sure_ that's what's happening? What makes you think so?

Comment: because it processes a bunch of files in a folder and deletes it after the complete execution. so the files are there.